# How do I get the price out of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am just finishing up this assignment for class. We are using sequential, and binary searches to ask customers for what part number they are looking for. Then return whether it was found or not, and if found return the price with the part number requested. So there are 2 arrays one with integers for the part number, and one double array for the price. So after the sequential and binary search look for the part number how do I get the price for that part number?

```
public class InventoryData 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] partNum = new int [200];
    double[] priceArray = new double[200];
    int partsCount = 0;
    int customerPart;
    int partPrice;
    String inventoryPricing;
    double customerPrice;

    public InventoryData(String File)
    {
        inventoryPricing = "file";
    }

    public void loadArrays()
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("file"));
            while(infile.hasNext())
            {
                partNum[partsCount] = infile.nextInt();
                priceArray[partPrice] = infile.nextDouble();
                ++partsCount;
            }
            infile.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            //If file has problems, set the count to -1
            partsCount = -1;
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void seqSearch()
    {
        System.out.println("What part number are you looking for?");
        customerPart = input.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i < partNum.length; i++){
            if(customerPart == partNum[i])
                System.out.println("Sequential search found part" + customerPart);

        }
    }
    public int binarySearch()
    {
        int first = 0;
        int mid=0;
        int last = partsCount - 1;
        boolean found = false;
        System.out.println("What part number are you looking for?");
        customerPart = input.nextInt();

        while(first <= last && !found)
        {
            mid = (last + first) /2;
            if(partNum[mid] == customerPart)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else if(partNum[mid] < customerPart)
                first = mid +1;
            else 
                last = mid-1;
        }
        if(!found)
        {
            mid = -1;
        }
        return mid;
    }
        public double getPrice()
        {
            return customerPrice; 
        }
}// end of inventory data class
```

Comment: Do the part and price arrays match up? `[0] - part = [0] - price`...

Comment: The `binary` search won't work unless the part array is sorted...

Comment: well I had my instructor look over the binary search, and he said it was correct. Its based off a flowchart he gave us as an example

Comment: The algorithm appears to be correct but will only work if the input from the file is sorted...

Comment: Anyway if the 2 arrays match up meaning the price for `part[0]` is stored in `price[0]` and not `price[50]` or something then you should be able to use the index of the found part to look up the price. If the found part is at index `25` then the price would be `price[25]`...

Comment: Do I miss something or does your price array only has 1 value because when you set a partPrice in the price array you use the part price field as index which is never incremented.

Comment: Right I changed up the code, and forgot to get rid of partPrice

Comment: play with indexes. Obtain the search index. Then you can obtain the part and price from respective arrays for same index position

Answer (score 0):

1st let me suggest something:
if you are learning how to develop apps then is ok, if yo are trying to rollout som product then think about not using such a logic, consider that the bigger the list is, the more hard would be to iterate over ALL the array until you maybe find something...

back to your question: :)

You are almost there...

in the for loop need to get the array price `priceArray` and get the element at the index..

the trick is hidden here:
**priceArray[i]**

## Look:

```
for(int i=0; i < partNum.length; i++){
    if(customerPart == partNum[i]){
        System.out.println("Sequential search found part" + customerPart);
        // here
        System.out.println("and the price is: " + priceArray[i]);
    }
}
```

so you will get the value of the price related to the user input...